# Does the DolphinDB language support not in syntax?

Tags: sql, dolphindb

Suppose I have the following table,

```
t=table(1..5 as id,6..10 as v)
```

I want to select the records from the table where id != 2 and id !=4 ,but I execute the following code ,

```
select * from t where  id  not in (2,4)
```

The error message is as follows,

```
Function not is not a binary operator
```

Does the DolphinDB language support not in syntax?

Comment: . . I would say that your error message is a pretty clear indication that DolphinDB does NOT support `NOT IN`.

Answer (score 1):

DolphinDB doesn't support the operator `not in`. But you can use two operators `not` and `in`to solve your problem.

```
select * from t where not id in (2,4)
```